# If specific CSS class is on page / hide another CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

on my page I try to make a separation between bought and unsold products. The bought products uses the CSS class "winning_bid" in a . If this class is on a page I would like to hide another  with the class "price". I would like to do something like the following structure in JS.

If CSS class "winning_bid" is on this page{
hide "price"
}else
display "winning_bid"}

Is this possible with JS. I need this case also for buttons.
If CSS class "winning_bid" is in a div{
hide specific button in this div
}else
display button

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It's definitely possible. Use `querySelector()` to determine if element exists, then hide the other(s). On SO, you're expected to make an attempt so we can have context and answer specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to support newer browsers, there is the [`:has()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) (which is [relatively widely supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has)) that you can use:

```css
body:has(.winning_bid) .price {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="winning_bid">Winning bid</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <!-- This element can be nested at any level, it doesn't matter -->
    <div class="price">Price</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This method has the advantage over JS in the sense that if your page is somehow a SPA or its contents are dynamically updated, you need to use MutationObserver to constantly watch changes to the DOM in order to determine if the element `.winning_bid` has been added to the document.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use document.querySelector to check if there are any elements with the "winning_bid" class and get all the elements with the price class using querySelectorAll or getElementsByClassName an example of this would be

```js
// querySelector returns null if there are no elements matching these selectors
if(document.querySelector(".winning_bid") != null) {
    // get all elements with the price class if there are elements with winning_bid class
    const elementsWithPriceClass = document.querySelectorAll(".price"){
    // iterate over the NodeList (elementsWithPriceClass)
    elementsWithPriceClass.forEach(element => {
        // hide the element
        element.style.display = "none"
    })
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but it should work in theory. Let me know about the results

Answer (score 0):

In javascript way you can refer the below solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>hide the elements if an item with class element is present</p>

<div class="element"></div>

<div class="example">Element1</div>
<div class="example">Element2</div>

<script>
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
if(element.length > 0){
const items = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
for (const item of items) {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```